# I want to create a chrome extension that will open a dialog to get a URL and then send it to a webhook

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i want to create a dialog like that:
[page dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfpKU.png)

I tried with this code:

```js
var input = prompt("Please enter a URL:"); fetch("https://hook.eu1.make.com/****", {   method: "POST",   headers: {     "Content-Type": "application/json"   },   body: JSON.stringify({     url: input   }) })   .then(response => response.json())   .then(data => console.log(data))   .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
```

But when I load the extension I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError:prompt is not defined
```

Comment: Do it in the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm quite a beginner so could you expand on that?

Comment: See [this official example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples/cookbook.offscreen-dom).